# How to define a subTree method

Tags: haskell

In this def will the subTree function work? 
I am a bit confused. 
now a leaf with String "s" can be considered as a sub tree if a node in the Tree contains String "s".

```
data Tree = Leaf String | Node Tree String Tree

subTree :: Tree -> Tree -> Bool
subTree (Leaf s) t = inTree s t
subTree (Node t1 s1 t2) (Leaf s2) = False
subTree (Node t1 s1 t2) (Node t3 s2 t4) = 
   ((s1 == s2) && (subTree t1 t3) && (subTree t2 t4)) ||
   subTree (Node t1 s1 t2) t3 ||
   subTree (Node t1 s1 t2) t4

inTree :: String -> Tree -> Bool
inTree s1 (Leaf s2) = (s1 == s2)
inTree s1 (Node t1 s2 t2) = (s1 == s2) || inTree s1 t1 || inTree s1 t2
```

Comment: Does anyone understand my question?
it seems like this is confusing. 
It is this line that is causing the confusion
inTree s1 (Node t1 s2 t2) = (s1 == s2) || inTree s1 t1 || inTree s1 t2

Answer (score 1):

```
*Main> subTree (Leaf 1) (Node (Leaf 0) 1 (Leaf 9))
True
*Main> subTree (Leaf 1) (Node (Leaf 1) 4 (Leaf 9))
True
*Main> subTree (Leaf 1) (Node (Leaf 0) 4 (Leaf 9))
False
*Main>
```

I changed String to Integer

Is this correct according to the def of subtree?

Comment: I think this is part of your question, not really an answer. The fact that there's an answer means people are less likely to add one themselves. Perhaps you'd like to edit this into your question and remove the answer?